# Doing SSH on Liferay and then it shutdowns when I exit terminal

Tags: tomcat, ssh, liferay, catalina

I do ssh on my terminal to run my liferay.

I use this command

```
ssh user@server.com
password: *****

cd tomcat/bin/

./catalina.sh run
```

Now when I run this command this will run my liferay just fine but when I exit my terminal it will also shut down my Liferay. causing my site to return "**Service Temporarily Unavailable**"

What is the proper way to run catalina script? Do I really need to keep my Terminal open to keep my server running? I think there's something wrong to what I did.

Using Liferay 6.0

Please advice.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the `startup.sh` script that usually ships with Tomcat (runs tomcat in the background) or use one of the many popular backgrounding techniques (`nohup`, `screen`, etc).

Comment: Do you have an explanation to what is happening to my approach? Is it really normal that when ever I run that line and I close my terminal it will also end my server? Thanks for the suggestion, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Pennf0lio Yes, basically when you close your window it sends the `HUP` signal to your program (meaning hangup). If a process doesn't know how to deal with this, it's usually just killed. You can use the `nohup` program to ignore the `HUP` signal, or the other methods described above.